# Custom events outside request in Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm trying to notify my custom event in `__init__` method of my application, and catch it/subscribe in included part of application. But for some reason the subscriber in imported code is not being called. If in this same imported code I subscribe to Pyramid event everything works. Here is the code example.

**__init__.py**

```
class MyEvent(object): pass

def main(...):
   ...
   config.include('some_module')
   config.registry.notify(MyEvent())
   ...
```

**some_module.py**

```
def handle_event(e):
  print 'event', e

def includeme(config):
  print 'module included'
  config.add_subscriber(handle_event, 'myapp.MyEvent')
```

The line `module included` is printed, but not the `event` line. Is this how notify/subscribe in Pyramid is suppose to work? Is there an error somewhere in the code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After you `config.include()` you will have to explicitly commit the `Configurator` using `config.commit()` before the `config.add_subscriber(...)` will have been added to the internal registry for use.

In other words, currently when you call `.notify(...)` there are no subscribers for the event registered yet.